# Identifying non-standard flange fastener/nut

Tags: fastener, flange

Can someone please identify this non-standard fastener/nut with flange.
The **thread is 10mm** (it fits a 10mm threaded rod) and the diameter of the **flange is 20mm**.

The **thread pitch is 1mm** if that helps to identify it.

I need to find another one of these to repair a lamp with a pottery base that has a 10mm threaded rod that is missing this piece. I have an identical lamp from which this fastener/nut  was taken to photograph it.

[image: Front view]
[image: Rear view]

Here is the nut fastened to the threaded rod from the other lamp to show how it is used. The flange is used to attach to the underside of the lamp base.

[image: Nut shown fastened to threaded rod]

I just need to find the name of this fastener/nut or where to buy it. Many thanks!

[Link to full sized image of front view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qi3DN.jpg)

[Link to full sized image of rear view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jGLZs.jpg)

[Link to full sized image of lamp holder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cd6EL.jpg)

Comment: Any hardware store should have lamp repair parts. Most have a fasteners aisle with several bins of lamp parts.  Any worker there should be able to help you find what you need.

Comment: @MikeSchroedel I have tried that (in fact spent many hours in total now trying different shops), and all I can find is various M10 nuts or M10 flange nuts that are several mm thick and not suitable. The closest option I could find was an M10 nut plus washer, which isn't satisfactory.

Comment: Ideally I'm looking for the technical name of this so that I can Google for it.

Comment: Try 'lamp nipple nut' . Do you have any broken lamps that you can swipe the part from? Have you tried other nuts?

Comment: Nothing special about the nut. It just combines a nut, in effect with a washer; why is that unsatisfactory?.  Too thick? Use a thin nut and thin washer. BTW, these nuts are quite common in the Americas, though they're easily deformed.

Comment: [Speed Nut](https://www.grainger.com/product/21VY94?gclid=Cj0KCQiAlZH_BRCgARIsAAZHSBlNFaEVBP09i28smt7Xa6yJfofYo09x4p2MsML7OE7GmfinrjpZP8IaAhOPEALw_wcB&cm_mmc=PPC:+Google+PLA&ef_id=Cj0KCQiAlZH_BRCgARIsAAZHSBlNFaEVBP09i28smt7Xa6yJfofYo09x4p2MsML7OE7GmfinrjpZP8IaAhOPEALw_wcB:G:s&s_kwcid=AL!2966!3!342902356446!!!g!349604050214!&gucid=N:N:PS:Paid:GGL:CSM-2295:4P7A1P:20501231) Grainger

Comment: [Genuine Mopar Stamped Hex Flange Nut](https://www.ebay.com/itm/Genuine-Mopar-Stamped-Hex-Flange-Nut-6512316AA-/264486473690) Ebay

Comment: @Mazura It definitely does look like a speed nut. Thank you! The next challenge for me is to find an M10 speed nut in the UK... They don't seem common

Answer (score 2):

That is nut is 1/8" pipe thread, which is what standard lamp pipe and fittings are. Any lamp shop (or even a decent hardware store) will have a variety of *lamp thread* fittings available, including lock nuts. I call it *lamp thread* because while it **is** 1/8" pipe thread, the pipe and fittings are not *tapered* like 1/8" pipe thread plumbing fittings are.

While you may not find an *identical* flanged nut like the example in your picture, it would be easy enough to use a regular *lamp thread* hex nut and use a washer to increase the surface area.

Comment: The manufacturer can get away with that stamped garbage. Anything you find at the store worth buying will be cast. Google **flange nut *stamped*** : first picture looks exactly like the OP's.

Comment: @Mazura When I Google for "flange nut stamped" I don't see it. Maybe because I'm in the UK and get different search results? Stamped flange nuts are not common in the UK it seems.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the picture I agree with Jimmy Fix-it, that looks like regular old lamp thread which is pretty standard. However you said it's definitely M10.

For situations like this I skip hardware stores and go straight to mcmaster.com. Search for nuts and look at the filters on the left side. Start entering what you know you need, such as M10, the type of metal, the overall height, etc. Here is a link to get you started:

[https://www.mcmaster.com/nuts/thread-size~m10/](https://www.mcmaster.com/nuts/thread-size%7Em10/)

I'm not associated but this is the best website on the internet as far as I'm concerned! Good luck.